# SlickGrid Column Groups

Tags: grouping, slickgrid, tablecolumn, tableheader

Is there a way to add a column groupings?  For example:

```
   Unit 1    |    Unit 2    |
Pre Mid Post | Pre Mid Post |
--- --- ---- | --- --- ---- |
 2   4   5   |  3   4   4   |
 1   2   4   |  3   4   5   |
```

Basically, I need a header row for Unit that has three subcolumns in the Unit group; Pre, Mid, and Post.

This concept can also be seen in following pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe this help you http://hariharanpalani.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-HeaderGrouping.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, There is no columns grouping available in slickgrid but i created a plugin for one level column group.Take a look
https://github.com/naresh-n/slickgrid-column-group

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately grouping columns is a low priority for the creator of slickgrid as you can see in the issue post [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/63)

Although that issue was written 2 years ago, it was asked again 5 months ago and there was no reply to that post.
Apart from that by looking at his updates in the git history there is no indication it is implemented in any way.

My only suggestion is to try and move to another component.
You could maybe see if this could fit your needs: [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/)
I actually saw a demo there that has groupings like you wanted: [demo](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid9_demo.html)

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this in the active SlickGrid repo: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Here's an example: http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-column-group.html